# Perl script, parse text file between words

Tags: perl, file, parsing, text

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
... //John/box/sandbox/users/abc/project/build/file2
... //John/box/sandbox/users/cde/project/build/file1
... //John/box/sandbox/users/hdf/project/config/file
```

Using a Perl script, how can I parse this file so that my final output is:

```
//John/box/sandbox/users/abc/project/
//John/box/sandbox/users/cde/project/
//John/box/sandbox/users/hdf/project/
```

Basically my ultimate goal is to search for "//" and "project" on the same line and then take everything between them.

Thanks for the fast response, Both doesn't seems to work for me
I'm using perl 5.8.3 build 809
`perl -nle 'print $1 if m@(//.*project/)@;' output.txt`

```
   use FileHandle;
   use Env;
   use Tk;
   use File::Copy;

   open(DAT, "output.txt") || die("Could not open file!");
   my $input = <DAT>;
   while (<$input>){
   chomp;
   print "$1\n" if ($_ =~ /(^\/\/.*project\/)/);
   }
```

Everyone thank you for your help. It worked fine, i had to remove `^`. 
For future questions i will add my work, sorry this is my first question. Human make mistakes :)

Comment: What have you tried? It's considered bad form to ask "how do I write a program that does this" without putting any work into it yourself.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is not an adequate description of the problem.

Comment: What's "build 809"? Is this an ActiveState build? On Windows? It's because you didn't use the proper syntax for your shell!

Comment: sorry, this was my first question . Btw i did tried it myself, it's just that i didn't add my work in the question.

Comment: I meant you didn't how it doesn't work. What input? What output? What error? In fact, you indicate you're not even sure it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, if you are using Windows, you need to use Double Quotes in the Command Prompt. Single quotes will give `Can't find string terminator` errors.

Comment: Please, add pragmas to the script: use strict; and use warnings;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $infile = 'in.txt';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";   

while (<$input>){
    chomp;
    print "$1\n" if ($_ =~ /(\/\/.*project\/)/);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but both doesn't seems to work for me. i'm using perl version 5.8.3 build 809. #perl -nle 'print $1 if m@(//.*project/)@;' output.txt

open(DAT, "output.txt") || die("Could not open file!");
my $input = <DAT>;

while (<$input>){
chomp;
print "$1\n" if ($_ =~ /(^\/\/.*project\/)/);
}

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough to do as a command-line filter:

```
perl -nle'print $1 if m@(//.*project/)@;' output.txt
```

Comment: @ikegami There seems lately to be a fashion against starting a pipeline with `cat`, and for the life of me I can't understand why; on modern hardware it seems improbable this should make any difference in efficiency (even [this page arguing against it](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-badunixhabits.html#ten) shows only a .005s difference), and providing a clearly visible source for the bytes flowing through the pipeline does a considerable amount for the readability of the result. Is it just a fad, or is there real sense behind it?

Comment: It's hardly a fad, the [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) has been around since 1995.

Comment: It makes it harder to detect errors, for one. An error from `cat` will leave `$?` with `0`. Note that `<foo perl ...` works fine if someone wants the input at the front.

Comment: @TLP It no longer seems to be a going concern, though. @ikegami A point in the context of canning a pipeline for use by another script, but if I'm typing at the command line, I won't be relying on $? to find out whether something went wrong. And `<foo perl ...` looks like I'm redirecting `foo` into my prompt, which has the same problem with regard to wasting brain cycles as does putting the input file after the filter into which it's going.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but both doesn't seems to work for me. i'm using perl version 5.8.3 build 809. #perl -nle 'print $1 if m@(//.*project/)@;' output.txt

open(DAT, "output.txt") || die("Could not open file!");
my $input = <DAT>;

while (<$input>){
chomp;
print "$1\n" if ($_ =~ /(^\/\/.*project\/)/);
}

Comment: @user3075765 You might add that code to your question -- as it is in your comment, it's nigh unreadable.